# Firebase Auth successful, but Database Ref set and update does not happen in electron app version 1.4.2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, electron

I'm able to authorize the Firebase app from my existing Electron app using `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken`. The promise for this method resolves and I'm able to obtain the current authorized user with `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`.

At this point I must technically be able to write to `/users/<currentUser>`. However calling the `userRef.set()` and `userRef.update()` methods does not update the database reference and fails silently (both the callback and the promise from these methods do not resolve and there is no error thrown).

What is strange is that the exact same code works in a different, newly created Electron app. My code looks like below:

```
const writeToFirebase = (customToken) => {
 syncApp.auth().signInWithCustomToken(customToken).then(user => {
  const userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;  // this is successfull
  const userRef = firebase.database().ref("/users/" + userId);
  userRef.set({data: data}, () => { //callback does not trigger });
  userRef.update({data: data})
   .then(() => {//promise does not resolve})
   .catch(err) => {// promise is not rejected either! }
 });
}
```

Any pointers on how to go about debugging this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the problem. It's unlikely anybody else would have the same issue, but if you do, take a look at the userAgent value in your `browserWindow.loadURL` in Electron.

Mine was set to an Android mobile device & Firebase was not setting/updating due to this reason. I presume the Firebase server reacts differently when it sees a mobile userAgent and I was using the Firebase JS SDK and not the Android SDK which caused the issue.